# How do I get rid of this error message on VSCode?

Tags: kotlin, terminal

When I run my code like this:

justiniverson@MacBook-Air-3 Fundies 1 % kotlin hw1-p1.main.kts

I get this warning and my code doesn't run as intended:

warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: /Users/justiniverson/Desktop/coding%20and%20stuff/Fundies%201/.

I've looked around to try and find how to fix the "classpath entry points to a non-existant location" error but most of the advice is tellling me to just update the software (I'm up to date).

If anyone has any insight on how I can fix this that would be greatly appreciated.

I restarted everything and thought maybe it was because I had my code in a folder on my desktop. I moved everything to my downloads and still get the same error message. I might delete all folders I currently have for VScode and try to start out fresh (?) but I doubt that would solve the issue.

Comment: Are you setting `$CLASSPATH` anywhere (e.g. in a shell startup script)? Does the folder in the error message, or anything like it, exist?

Answer (score 0):

Start by avoiding spaces in your folders/paths